# Prestashop shopping cart

Tags: php, prestashop

I have recently implemented an online store in prestashop. After installing and testing a payment gateway I then uninstalled and disabled modules that i dont use. Now i have a bit of a bizarre problem.

1. I can only add 1 item to the shopping cart. When I try to add more than one item nothing happens and there are no javascript errors.
2. When I navigate away from the page where I added items to the cart. The cart goes from

> Cart : 1 product

To

> Cart : (empty)

Has anyone ever encountered this problem in Prestashop 1.5.2.0 ?

Could it be a module I disabled or a PHP configuration problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was a cookie related issue. Managed to solve it by just clearing cookies or running the browser in incognito. Will log this issue with the developers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with sessions. You could do a quick test to check that sessions are supported in your environment.

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['test']==1)
{
    echo 'It worked. My Session ID is '.session_id();
}
$_SESSION['test']=1;
```

Comment: Works the second time.... I get > It worked. My Session ID is 952b751c2c4b3ced6aa9a98f233d1969

Comment: Interestingly enough I just realized that I cant login as well on the front end. It just redirects me to the login page.

Answer (score -1):

You can also clear the compiled smarty cache in your PrestaShop files.

Comment: Thanks Martin Bean, more specifically, was this just the browser cache? or did you clear the PrestaShop compiled smarty cache as well?

Comment: @BenjaminUtterback I cleared the browser cache. How I figure it out is I accessed the site in incognito mode and realized it worked. So cleared the cache in my chrome browser.